# Can I store an entire graph in the Java HttpSession?

Tags: java, servlets, httpsession

I am developing a web application which basically lets the user create a graph in his browser (in the server the graph is basically a List of nodes and each node has a List of edges). Each node or edge that the user creates or deletes is communicated to the server via Ajax, so the server can construct an equal graph represented by Java Objects.
This application is a web version of a desktop one. So I would like to offer to the user the option of "save" the graph. My initial idea was persist the object in a database when the user clicks the save button, but for this I need to keep my graph in the user's session.

So can I store a graph (which is a collection of nodes and edges) inside the http session or there is a better way to achieve what I want?

Obs: I was thinking of manipulating the graph directly in the database, that is, the graph is always persisted and if the user session expires I delete the graph of the database if it has not been saved yet.

Comment: Keeping conversational state on the server always has a negative effect on scalability and will require you to provide more server resources. I understand that you are maintaining the state of the complete graph in the client. If you already achieved that I think you should not interact with the server unless the user wants to save the graph.

Comment: Do you believe that I had not considered that possibility? I can not do that exactly, but I can make it almost. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer depends on the scale of your app.

**If you have only one server with enough memory to hold sessions for all your concurrent users**

Storing info in the session is the easiest thing to do. Make sure that your graph is serializable and Servlet (or J2EE) container will take of the rest. You can help with httpsession persistence if you implement some custom algo for your data.

**If you grew big**

That is if you have more than one server with a load balancer in front or your graphs do not fit in memory. Store them in some shared storage - either DB or a filer and retrieve by some key lookup.
Consider using sticky sessions to minimize DB/file lookups and cache recent graphs in memory

**Fancy trick**

If you find a way to compress your whole graph into 1-2KB put it entirely into http cookie, browser will send it back to you on every request, your server will be stateless, no DB, no session affinity issue.

Comment: If my application is already prepared to use a database you think is best to do so now?

Comment: I would not bother with DB until I had to deploy more than 1 server

Comment: As a user must extensively manipulate a graph my server will receive many requests (much more than a common site). Do you think this can be a bottleneck when dealing with databases?

Comment: yes, DB will be a bottleneck. This is not uncommon. Once it really become a big problem, you will have 1M+ monthly active users.